# Trolling "Whats the next number of this sequence"

Tags: sequences-and-series

I looked at [Predict next number from a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144881/predict-next-number-from-a-series) and [Next number in series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74585/next-number-in-series) but I did not found the answer I was looking for.

Is it possible to construct a rule for a sequence, that generates arbitrary elements?

For example $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are given and I have to find $x_5$. Can I come up with a rule which produces $x_{1-4}$ and any possible integer for $x_5$?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/819382/63095) could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation) you can create polynomials that are $1$ at one value of $x$ and $0$ at other values.  For your example, we have five of them, which will be of fourth degree.  We have $p_i(j)=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kroenecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kroenecker_delta), $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.  Let $y_i$ be the desired value of the sequence at $x=i$.  Then $y=\sum_{i=1}^5 y_ip_i$ is the polynomial you want.  There are many other functions that satisfy this.  You can add any number times $(x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-5)$.  Instead of polynomials you can use trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by taking an interpolating polynomial, through the 5 points.
They are many non polynomial functions also.

For a polynomial example $f(x)=\dfrac{y_1(x-2)}{1-2}+\dfrac{y_2(x-1)}{2-1} +\lambda(x-1)(x-2)$
This takes values $y_1,y_2$ at 1 and 2 and a  value depend on $\lambda$
 at 3,4,etc.

We can have $f(1)=y_1,f(2)=y_2\dots$ and so on with all the other numbers taking whatever value you want. This is not generally polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a function which generates arbitrary $x_5$ for given $x_{1-4}$ (hint- look at polynomials of a certain degree.)